# Parsing iTunes json, then displaying it on webpage, and caching it with PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing, itunes

I'm working on a project where I need to get info from iTunes, cache it, and display it on a webpage with PHP.  I prefer to use curl, since it seems faster, but I'm more familiar with get_file_contents.  An example of the json url is http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=284910350.  I'm able to grab and decode it, but I'm having trouble from there.

Here's my start:

```
<?php

    $cas = curl_init('http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=284910350');
    curl_setopt($cas, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $jsonitunes = curl_exec($cas);
    curl_close($cas);

    $arr = json_decode($jsonitunes,true);
    foreach($arr as $item) {
        echo "kind: ". $item['kind'] ."<br>"; 
    }


?>
```

I can print the array, or var_dump it, but can't seem to grab any values.  After that, I need to cache the whole thing.  If possible, I'd like to set it up to grab new content when it arrives, or on a frequent schedule without weighing down the server.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies:  I've posted what I had thus far...

Comment: Can you post the array structure retrieved? i.e, print_r($arr);

Comment: The is another nested level. So you should use: $arr['results'][0]['kind'] outside the foreach.

Comment: Sweet.  Thanks a bunch.  Got the nested level.  Now is there any easy way to cache this content, and check it on a frequent schedule or whenever there are changes?

Comment: For caching you can save it on a file or in a database. For checking changes you should perform a periodical check by using a system tool like crontab and do a comparison between the old cached json and the new json recovered from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  kind in /var/www/html/frank/scratch.php on line 9
```

That should be your first clue (make sure you're logging notices somewhere where you can see them as you work).  When you see that, you know you're referencing the array incorrectly.

Your next step should be

```
var_dump($arr);
```

to see where the key you're looking for actually is.

Then you should see that you actually need

```
foreach($arr['results'] as $item) {
```

Comment: YES!!  Thank you.  That was it for the array variable. Now, once I have the content, is there any easy way to cache it, and check back on a certain schedule or when content is new?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function? You should be able to use cURL to download the contents of that page, store it in a variable, then use json_decode.

Comment: Thanks!  Got that, but can't seem to get the variables out.

Answer (score 1):

```
<pre>
<?php

    $ch = curl_init("http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=284910350");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $jsonDecoded = json_decode($content, true);
    echo $jsonDecoded['results'][0]['artistName'];

?>
</pre>
```

Comment: Yes, I was writing while your post was edited. I modified the sources as you required.